# Draw the Archimedean Spiral

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

### Overview

I was playing with Desmos and discovered a really cool spiral:

[image: Archimedian Spiral]

Doing some research, I discovered that this spiral was the [Archimedian spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral). Every point on the spiral is exactly \$\theta\$ away from the origin, where \$\theta\$ is the angle from the origin. That is,  any point on the spiral has the polar coordinates \$(\theta, \theta)\$. This also has the consequence that the shortest distance between 2 arms of the spiral is exactly \$2\pi\$ if using radians or \$360\$ if using degrees.

### The Challenge

The basic spiral can be defined by the following formula in the polar coordinate system:
$$
r = a\theta
$$
Where \$a\$ is the multiplier of the distance between the arms. Your job is, given a floating point input for \$a\$, draw this spiral with *at least one* full rotation. You may output the image according to any [image I/O defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9093/default-acceptable-image-i-o-methods-for-image-related-challenges).

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: _You may use either degrees or radians for \$\theta\$, but not anything else._ Does it really matter? Unless we are required to draw the axis and make the scale explicit, this looks like a non-observable requirement.

Comment: @Arnauld I guess that's a fair point

Answer (score 10):

## Minecraft Command Blocks, 599 bytes

[image: command block pic]

### Commands

Left column (bottom block 0, 4, -2)

```
scoreboard objectives add c dummy
scoreboard players set m c 1
summon armor_stand 0 0 0
setblock 0 3 0 redstone_block
```

Middle column (bottom block 0, 4, 0)

```
execute at @e[type=armor_stand] run setblock ~ ~ ~ stone
tp @e[type=armor_stand] 0 0 0
execute as @e[type=armor_stand] at @s run tp @s ~ ~ ~ ~5 ~
scoreboard players reset d
scoreboard players add m c 1
setblock 0 3 1 air
setblock 0 3 1 redstone_block
```

Right column (bottom block 0, 4, 1)

```
execute as @e[type=armor_stand] at @s run tp @s ^ ^ ^<Input>
scoreboard players add d c 1
setblock 0 3 1 air
setblock 0 3 0 air
execute unless score d c = m c run setblock 0 3 1 redstone_block
execute if score d c = m c run setblock 0 3 0 redstone_block
```

The distance multiplier is set in the first command block in the right column. Hardcoding inputs is not allowed by codegolf rules, but there isn't any other way to take input in Minecraft.

When ran for an hour with an input of 0.1 it produced this. It starts skipping blocks after a little over one rotation but it does complete one full rotation.
[image: spiral]

Comment: does `tp @s ^ ^ ^<Input>` cause the armour stand to rotate?

Comment: Nice one! Minecraft answers seem to be so rare in CGCC.

Comment: @user253751 `tp @s ^ ^ ^<Input>` teleports the armor stand <Input> blocks in the direction it's facing. `tp @s ~ ~ ~ ~5 ~` is the command that rotates it.

Answer (score 7):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), 14 bytes

```
r=\ans_1\theta
```

Well...

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fad9sga6st)

Comment: Hardcoding the input in a variable (in your program, it's the variable `a`) is [not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/8731#8731). A program that would better conform to the I/O standards set by the community would be `r=\ans_1\theta`, where the input number is placed in the second expression box. [Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fad9sga6st)

Comment: @AidenChow Forgot about `\ans_0`. Thanks

Comment: Btw, you forgot edit this answer into the Desmos answers list [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24711/96039).

Answer (score 5):

## [GFA-Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFA_BASIC) 3.51 (Atari ST), 68 bytes

A manually edited listing in .LST format. All lines end with `CR`, including the last one.

```
PRO d(a)
F t=0TO 251
PL 160+t*COS(t/20)*a,100-t*SIN(t/20)*a
N t
RET
```

which expands to:

```
PROCEDURE d(a)
  FOR t=0 TO 251
    PLOT 160+t*COS(t/20)*a,100-t*SIN(t/20)*a
  NEXT t
RETURN
```

NB: We use \$251\$ as the upper bound so that the curve stops on the x-axis rather than at some random position (because \$251/20\approx 4\pi\$).

#### Example output

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 bytes

```
PolarPlot[y#,{y,0,7}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyA/J7EoICe/JLpSWae6UsdAx7w2Vu1/QFFmXolDWrShQex/AA)

I picked 7 for the plot range because it's a one-digit number that is close to \$2\pi\$ (so we get just around 1 rotation, slightly more).

Example result for input = 1:

[image: example result]

Example when we replace 7 with 50 (makes it more accurate to the image in the original post, but is one byte longer):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 28 bytes

```
plot@(**r.@o.@])(%~8*i.)@1e5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/vyAnv8RBQ0urSM8hX88hVlNDtc5CK1NP08Ew1fS/n5Oeglt@kUJSZUmqQnJ@aV5JZl66Qn5eTqWegkKIp79CcmKeeolCQVF@SmlyqkJmbmJ6arHefwA)

a=1
[image: One]

a=2
[image: Two]

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 49 bytes

```r
function(a)plot(cos(t<-0:9e3/1e3)*t*a,sin(t)*t*a)
```

[Try it on rdrr.io!](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(a)plot(cos(t%3C-0%3A9e3%2F1e3)*t*a%2Csin(t)*t*a)%0Af(3))

Comment: I think `a` is supposed to be taken as input.

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks, I somehow didn't notice this.

Comment: @pajonk - I think you can get away with only [99 points per quadrant](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(a)plot(cos(t%3C-0%3A999%2F99)*t*a%2Csin(t)*t*a)%0Af(3)) to save a byte...  but [using complex numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247439/95126) gives even bigger savings...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen hmm, I think I'll stick to the larger value, so it looks more like a line. The imaginary numbers idea - brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
9W:9/tJ*Ze*XG
```

Try it at [MATL online!](https://matl.io/?code=9W%3A9%2FtJ%2aZe%2aXG&inputs=&version=22.5.0)

#### Explanation

```
9W    % Push 9. 2 raised to that. Gives 512
:     % Range. Gives [1 2 ... 512] 
9/    % Divide each entry by 9
t     % Duplicate
J*    % Multiply each entry by imaginary unit
Ze    % Exponential of each entry
*     % Multiply each pair of entries
XG    % Plot
```

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 50 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
(•math.Sin•Plot○(⊢×↕∘≠)•math.Cos)-2×π×999⥊99÷˜↕100
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=beKGkCjigKJtYXRoLlNpbuKAolBsb3Til4so4oqiw5fihpXiiJjiiaAp4oCibWF0aC5Db3MpLTLDl8+Aw5c5OTnipYo5OcO3y5zihpUxMDA=)

The JS version of BQN has a plotting builtin, which I used for the same rosetta code task. This is just a golf of that.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel & VBA, 144 bytes

```
Cell B1 = SEQUENCE(90)/9*PI()
Cell C1 = B1#*COS(B1#)*A1
Cell D1 = B1#*SIN(B1#)*A1
VBA Immediate Window Set x=activesheet.Shapes.AddChart2(,73,,,,360):x.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("C1:D96")
```

Could cut the `,,,,360` if the plot doesn't have to be square.
[image: Excel Plot]

Comment: You can get this down to somewhere around 109 bytes if you change cell B1's formula to `=ROW(1:90)/9*PI()` and the immediate window function to `Sheet1.Shapes.AddChart2(,73,,,,360).Chart.SetSourceData[C1:D90]`

Answer (score 2):

## [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), <sup><s>69</s></sup> 68 bytes

```python
lambda a,t=var('t'):parametric_plot((a*t*cos(t),a*t*sin(t)),(t,0,9))
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs43h5cpJzE1KSVRI1CmxLUss0lAvUde0KkgsSsxNLSnKTI4vyMkv0dBI1CrRSs4v1ijR1AExizPzgExNHY0SHQMdS01NXi5erjQNQ00AIRsXsw==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

*Saved a byte thanks to [Seggan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107299/seggan)!!!*

[image: Current graph]

#### Original graph using 42 instead of 9

[image: Original graph (0,42)]

Comment: You can replace the `42` with a `7`, `8`, or `9` to save 1 byte, although the graph wont be as big

Comment: @Seggan But it looks so cool! :D

Comment: @Seggan But a golf is a golf - thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

### SVG(HTML5) + JavaScript (ES6), <s>77</s> 76 + 96 = 172 bytes

```js
f=a=>s.setAttribute("points",[...Array(9e3)].map((_,i)=>[Math.sin(i/=100)*i*a,Math.cos(i)*i*a]))
;f(.1)
```

```html
<input value=.1 oninput=f(+value)><br>
<svg viewBox=-4,-4,8,8><polyline id=s fill=none stroke=red stroke-width=.05>
```

Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @Kaiido.

Comment: You can omit the leading 0 in `stroke-width`. And I didn't check if it's part of your count but you can also remove `this.` in `f(this.value)`

Comment: @Kaiido There's a story behind that `0` - I was fiddling around trying to get something to work, but my problem was that I had a `/`, so nothing was working. Later I figured that I could remove the `/`, but forgot to remove the `0`. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 42 bytes*

```r
function(a,x=0:6e3/1e3)plot(a*x*pi*1i^x/2)
```

[Try it at rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(a%2Cx%3D0%3A6e3%2F1e3)plot(a*x*pi*1i%5Ex%2F2)%0A%0Af(3))

Calculates the the points of the spiral as the real and imaginary parts of complex numbers, which is conveniently displayed directly as points on the complex plane by the [R](https://www.r-project.org/) `plot` function.

*The `*pi`...`/2` bit here is to scale the image so that the angle is in *radians* and achieve a distance between arms of exactly `2*pi`.  If we use an alternative [unit of angular measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Units), such as *quadrants*, we could drop this for [37 bytes](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(a%2Cx%3D0%3A6e3%2F1e3)plot(a*x*pi*1i%5Ex%2F2)%0A%0Af(3)): `function(a,x=0:6e3/1e3)plot(a*x*1i^x)`.

Note also that the choice of `1e3` plotted points per quadrant was chosen to allow direct competition with [pajonk's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247272/95126); however, `99` plotted points per quadrant also gives a satisfactory output (the points overlap) and [saves another byte](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(a%2Cx%3D0%3A999%2F99)plot(a*x*1i%5Ex)%0A%0Af(3)): `function(a,x=0:999/99)plot(a*x*1i^x)`.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + pracma library, 39 bytes

```r
function(a)pracma::polar(r<-0:99/9,a*r)
```

[Try it at rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(a)pracma%3A%3Apolar(r%3C-0%3A99%2F9%2Ca*r)%0Af(3))

Using a dedicated `polar` function doesn't save much, if anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

### Applesoft BASIC, 73 bytes

```
0GR
1COLOR=7
2INPUTR
3I=0
4PLOTCOS(I)*I*R+20,SIN(I)*I*R+20
5I=I+.1
6GOTO4
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Clojure, 344 bytes**

```
(defn s[a](doto(JFrame."")(.setPreferredSize(Dimension. 500 500))(.add(doto(proxy[JPanel][](paintComponent[g](.drawPolyline g (into-array Integer/TYPE(map #(+ 250(* a(/ % 20)(Math/cos(Math/toRadians %))))(range 3600)))(into-array Integer/TYPE(map #(- 250(* a(/ % 20)(Math/sin(Math/toRadians %))))(range 3600)))3600))))).pack(.setVisible true)))
```

**Output for `(s 1)`:**

[image: Spiral]